# Sqlite and SharedPreference runtime permission check

Tags: android

If my Android application uses [SharedPrefrences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) and Sqlite database, does it need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE runtime checks when I use database and/or SharedPrefrences in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and are required when you intend to   read/write to external storage.

**Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE):**

> Starting in API level 19, this permission is not required to
>   read/write files in your application-specific directories returned by
>   getExternalFilesDir(String) and getExternalCacheDir().

Since `SharedPrefrences` and database are stored in your application's sandbox or app specific directories, you don't need these permission.

Answer (score 1):

**No it does'nt require any permission.**

`SharedPreferences` and `SQLite` Database do not need any kind of permission.
You can check documentations also.

1)[`SharedPreference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

2)[`SQLite`](https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html)

If its stated in document,to use permission for any element,than you need to use it.

Else, there is no need of permission for required element.

I Hope it helps,thank you.
if its not the answer,please ignore the answer.